# JPA Two lazy collections in one entity - how to run JPA query to get entity and only one collection

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee, jpql

I have a problem with write correct JPA query to get entity with one filled collection. For example I have entity with two collections (I want to have FetchType.LAZY for both collections):

```
public class Entity {

private String value;   

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="entity_id")
private List<ElementA> elementsA;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="entity_id")
private List<ElementB> elementsB;
```

}

And I want to run JPA query and get only information about Entity and collection 'elementsA'. I was trying with:

```
"From Entity e join fetch e.elementsA eA"
```

But I've got error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: 
failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: 
model.jpa.entities.Entity.elementsB, 
could not initialize proxy - no Session
```

How I should write this query to fetch only information about collection 'elementsA'.

Thanks, Darek.

Comment: FWIW JPQL starts with "SELECT e", without that is non-portable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your fetching is correct, but your exception is indicating that later after session is closed, somewhere in the code you're calling `entity.getElementsB();` which triggers another query/fetch, which results in `LazyInitializationException` because session is closed at that point.